# A question on the properties of Lipschitz space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For an open $\Omega \in \mathbb R^n$, consider
$$ \Lambda_1(\Omega)=\Big\{ f:\Lambda\mapsto\mathbb R: \sup_{h\neq 0}\frac{|f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)|}{h}+\|f\|_{L^\infty}<\infty \Big\} $$
$$ \text{Lip}_1(\Omega)=\Big\{ f:\Lambda\mapsto\mathbb R: \sup_{h\neq 0}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{h}+\|f\|_{L^\infty}<\infty \Big\} $$
Prove that $\Lambda_1(\Omega)\supsetneq \text{Lip}_1(\Omega)$

Now I got that the $\supset$ part is easy, but how can I find a function $f\in\Lambda_1(\Omega)$ but $f\notin \text{Lip}_1(\Omega)$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the function $f:(-1,1)\to \mathbb R$, $f(x):=\mathrm{sgn}(x)x^{0.5}$ does the trick. For $h>0$, $$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=h^{-0.5}\to \infty, \quad\text{as $h\to$ 0},$$ so $f\notin\mathrm{Lip}_1.$

Note that it suffices to check finiteness of your supremum only for $x=0$, as elsewhere the function is smooth: $$\frac{f(h)+f(-h)-2f(0)}{h}=0,\quad\forall\;h\neq 0,$$ so that $f\in\Lambda_1$.